# Bogus message from automatic updates

Tags: updates, unattended-upgrades

When I ssh into my Ubuntu 18.04 box I get the motd

`1 update could not be installed automatically`

Which goes on to tell me to check the unattended-upgrades log.

The log shows no problems. How can I clear this bogus message?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, it wasn't bogus.

Turns out the script

`/etc/update-motd.d/92-unattended-upgrades`

produces this message at login.

This script references

`/usr/share/unattended-upgrades/update-motd-unattended-upgrades`

which in turn looks at the contents of

`/var/lib/unattended-upgrades/kept-back`

In my case this last file was non-blank because `unattended-upgrades` tried to update `vino`, which I have pinned to an old version on this Lubuntu box, because the latest version removes the options dialog.

Deleting `/var/lib/unattended-upgrades/kept-back` made the message go away - but only till the next time `unattended-upgrades` ran.

But there was nothing in the logs that it told me to reference about it!!

Comment: Removing the kept-back file solves the issue, but it would be interesting to run "apt dist-upgrade" before doing so.

Comment: So, it's definitely not bogus, but it is (was) a bug in `unattended-upgrades`, that was fixed sometime between 18.04 and 20.04. Basically, even on a successful run of `unattended-upgrades`, the `kept-back` file would **NOT** be deleted.  That behavior is fixed in the latest version.

Comment: @crimson-egret It wasn't fixed so much in my system (20.04). I too had to remove it manually. I did it after having tried `sudo apt install <package kept back>` told me that those packages were already the newest version, so I think it was just a bug/bogus message.

Comment: The same on my 20.04. Is there an open issue for that somewhere already? Or closed one claiming that it was fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this it the right way, but after I saw this discussion, I found there was NO kept-back file in `/var/lib/unattended-upgrades/` in my environment.
Thus, I tried making the kept-back file.

```bash
sudo touch /var/lib/unattended-upgrades/kept-back
sudo reboot
```

Then,

```bash
0 update could not be installed automatically
```

appeared instead of

```bash
20 update could not be installed automatically
```

(In my case, the number was 20, not 1.)
Then, I tried unattended-upgrades and rebooted again as below.

```bash
sudo unattended-upgrades
sudo reboot
```

After this, the `20 update could not be installed automatically` message never appears.